# Did Realm support model version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, swift, realm

I'm getting start with Realm but I didn't find any info about how to handle model version.For example,I want to add/delete some properties in next version of my app.Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is realm's documentation page about the migration: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations .

The deleted and added properties will be automatically migrated if you specify a higher schema version number in your Realm.Configuration. You only need to use the migration block if you want to do real migration, like mapping a property to another.

```
let realmConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
    path: nil,
    inMemoryIdentifier: nil,
    encryptionKey: nil,
    readOnly: false,
    schemaVersion: schemaVersionNumber,
    migrationBlock: migrationBlock,
    objectTypes: nil)

do {
    realm = try Realm(configuration: realmConfiguration)
    print("[REALM] Path: \(realm.path)")
} catch let error as NSError {
    fatalError("Error opening realm: \(error)")
}
```